# Go- Why Does My For Loop Throw "Unexpected Semi-colon or New-line"?

Tags: go

I'm writing a dice rolling function. In order to add the result of each die, I added to an output variable using a for loop. However, I'm getting an error thrown when I attempt to build;

> syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline, expecting {

This was thrown on the line initializing the for loop.
Here is my code:

```
    for i := 0; i < [0]si; i++ {
        output := output + mt.Intn([1]si)
    }
```

si is simply an int array holding 2 values, and mt is the name I gave to math/rand when I imported it.

Comment: You might get better answers, if you provide a minimal complete source file illustrating the problem, so that we don't need to guess what `mt` and `si` stand for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop has several problems:

1. The use of square brackets is odd.  Outside of type definitions, these go after slice/array names, e.g. `x[i]` would give you the *i*th element of the slice `x`.
2. There is no reference to `i` inside the loop body, and thus each iteration of the loop will do the same thing.
3. You should probably write `output = output + ...` without the colon.  Otherwise, a new variable `output` is declared during each iteration of the loop, and forgotten immediately after so that the loop has no effect.

The compiler error is probably caused by the first of these problems.

Comment: Ohp, yeah that fixed it. I assumed that since types have the brackets before the type name, it would be the same for variables. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You access an array with varname[idx] in Go, just like in most other languages. It's only when declaring a new array of type si that you use the [size]si prefix syntax. You're getting the error because your code is syntactically invalid. You're trying to compare i to an array of 0 si s.